# How to initialize const member requiring computations to be performed?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constants

I understand that for a class

```
class A { 
     const int myint;
  public:
     A (const int yourint);
     A (const std::string yourstring);
};
```

I could initialize `myint` in the initializer list like so:

```
A::A (const int yourint) : myint (yourint) {};
```

However, what is the proper way of initializing `myint` from the second constructor if the the data required to compute it comes say from a string and the computations may be involved?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a function call inside a delegating (if avaliable, not neccessarily) constructor's member initialization list:

```
A::A(std::string const& yourstring) : A(compute_myint(yourstring)) {};
```

<sup>Pass `std::string` by `const&`, not just `const`, while you're at it.</sup>

`compute_myint` can be non-member, static member, possibly not accessible from outside the class, whichever makes the most sense.

Answer (score 11):

Here you would want to use delegating constructors, if you can, or you could compute in the ctor. See my second example for the second option. An example for your class would be:

### Option 1: Delegating Constructors: C++11 forward

```
class A { 
     const int myint;
     static int parse_int(const std::string& string) {/*...*/}
  public:
     A (const int yourint) : myint{yourint};
     A (const std::string yourstring) : A{parse_int(yourstring)};
}
```

By the way, since `parse_int` only computes integers, then it could be `static`, meaning it does not require a class instance to be used. Of course, there is no requirement, as the function could be a member just as well, (non `static`), although `static` is safer, since it will almost always guarantee the construction of the object.

### Option 2: Constructor Computation, non delegating

This method could be used in any C++ version.

```
class A { 
     const int myint;
     static int parse_int(const std::string& string) {/*...*/}
  public:
     A (const int yourint) : myint(yourint);
     A (const std::string yourstring) : my_int(parse_int(yourstring));
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution for pre-C++11.

Answer (score 10):

Just use a member function.

Keep in mind that it's safer (i.e. less error-prone) to use a `static` member function for things like this than a non-static one, because the class isn't fully initialized yet when the function is called.

```
class A {
  const int myint;
public:
  A(const int x) : myint(x) {}
  A(std::string const& s) : myint(compute(s)) {}
private:
  static int compute(std::string const& s) { return (int)s.length(); }
};
```

Comment: I find it a lot safer to use a file-scoped function (static keyword) in the class implementation file. Then it doesn't clutter up the header when people read it. Of course then you can't write your constructor function inline.

Answer (score 7):

I've been annoyed by this issue quite a few times, so I have developed a small utility to solve it in the general case. The full code is as follows:

```
namespace initBlock_detail {
    struct tag { };

    template <class F>
    decltype(auto) operator + (tag, F &&f) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)();
    }
}

#define initBlock \
    initBlock_detail::tag{} + [&]() -> decltype(auto)
```

And it is used as follows:

```
int const i = initBlock {
    // Any complex calculation
    // and then return the value
    return foo;
};
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be32f14f1f30502e)

The structure is similar to Andrei Alexandrescu's ScopeGuard implementation, which uses an infix operator overload and a lambda to achieve that light syntax. `i`'s type can be deduced, can be a reference, etc. Other useful features include the possibility to place `using namespace` declarations inside the init-block. Any movable and/or copyable type can be used.